# What is the web server of Meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I don't really understand what is the name of the web server from `meteor.js`.

Because in `PHP` for example, by default, we are using `ngix` (or apache).

In `python`, we are using `werkzeug` (it's not really a web server in this case, but a library but the objective is similar).

In `rails`, we are using by default `Puma`.

But impossible to know what we're using in Meteor. We don't have a specific web server ? we are only using Meteor ?
I know the fact that `meteor` is a client/server framework built on top of `nodejs` (on the server side), but i don't find more precise detail about the name or the type of web server.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why this is important at all to you? Meteor is deliberately designed deliberately to abstract away any need for you to even worry about such a facility.

Comment: @esqew Basically, i have two question : "What is the name of the web server" and "What type of server ?  (WSGI, ASGI, CGI etc...) ". And i'm trying to understand and answer this two questions.

Comment: @esqew And I know the answers won't be exactly as requested in the question, but I would like to get as close as possible

Comment: Open the MeteorJS source code and see what was implemented. https://github.com/meteor/meteor

Comment: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/webapp

Comment: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/meteor-base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node can serve up HTML pages, so unless you have some other situation going, it's the web server.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-web-server-in-node-js-with-the-http-module

Comment: For you, Node in meteor.js is the same as ngix in PHP for example or Puma in rails ?

Comment: PHP is a "hypertext processor" that can run alongside nginx, apache, and several other web servers.  PHP is external to the web server.

For rails, ruby can run on apache, puma, and others because it is also external to the web server.

Node has its OWN web server available, so you don't need an external web server.  Or you could write your code to run on top of other external web servers.

Comment: yeah i understand, but in that case, what is the type of server ? Because meteor don't use gateway to communicate, i don't understand what kind of interface meteor is using.

Comment: I think you're overlooking a piece here.  Anyone with understanding of socket programming can create an HTTP server.  It's just a program.  It doesn't have to have a "name".  The generic internal Node server can expose services that you make available, and it can serve HTML like any other web server.  With some tweaking you could probably execute PHP or Ruby with it.  Don't get stuck on this "name" thing.

Comment: I confess that I am forcing with the name because I have a question about it on one of my subjects. But yes, I don't have the impression that there is a precise name for this type of web server